# Disabling Listbox items in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on Windows Phone 7 Platform.

I am showing moonths of a year in a Listbox.

Now i want to enable only current month onwards in the Listbox, all previous months should be Disabled. Below is code to populate months of a year in a listobx.

Listboxobject.ItemsSource = globalobject.Getmonths;

public List Getmonths

```
        monthlist.Add("January");
        monthlist.Add("February");
        monthlist.Add("March");
        monthlist.Add("April");
        monthlist.Add("May");
        monthlist.Add("June");
        monthlist.Add("July");
        monthlist.Add("August");
        monthlist.Add("September");
        monthlist.Add("October");
        monthlist.Add("November");
        monthlist.Add("December");
        return monthlist;
```

Comment: sorry. Just edited my question.

Comment: Try to get the current month using date finding method. If the month is May then get the index of May in listbox.and add list.items.removeat(0) in a loop for 4 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you have to do. Take a note that I'm not setting ItemSource, just adding ListBoxItems one by one. It's important to add ListBoxItems and not strings, if you want to have item disabling functionality. If you have any problems I can send you the solution.

```
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            string mname = dt2.ToString("MMMM");
            ListBoxItem LBI = new ListBoxItem();
            LBI.Content = mname;
            if (dt.Month > dt2.Month)
                LBI.IsEnabled = false;
            Listboxobject.Items.Add(LBI);
            dt2 = dt2.AddMonths(1);
        }
```

Comment: ...Thanks.....it worked....one more question...i aslo need to get todays date of the month selecetd in the Listbox.

Comment: Once a Month is selected in Listbox also wants to restrict from selecting a date less than Todays date in the selected Month.

Comment: Just do the exact same logic, but there's a problem with different day count in all of the months. You can solve it by using C# built in day counter: DateTime.DaysInMonth((int)year, (int)month); Notice that you have to specify year as well for it to work in leap years.

Answer (score 0):

For each item in your listbos ie, for each listboxitem, it has got a property called IsEnabled. Its a bool proprty. You can set it false for disabling it.